# When the mouse is not activating a class, add it? Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, hover

I have two borders, one on the bottom of an H1, and the other on the right hand side of a div. I have them change color if the mouse is over either element. My idea is to change both borders to be the new color when the mouse is in neither.  I figure my best bet would be some sort of JavaScript logic.  Something like: if the mouse is not on a, and not on b, add id1 and id2, though I don't know how this will affect my id1 and id2 when the mouse goes back to them.

Is this the right answer, or is there another way I can do this? In case you're wondering the border is 2px wide. I am very new to JavaScript. So to recap, what I want is, the borders of my h1 and div to change when the mouse hovers over them, when the mouse is on neither, I wan't both borders to change at the same time. I'm after the simplest least messy way of solving this.

Comment: Are the h3 and the div adjacent?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by applying css only when their container is hovered.  Check out the snippet!

```css
.container {
   display:block;
   width:100px;
}

.container:hover h1 {
  border-right:solid 2px red;
}
.container:hover div {
  border-top:solid 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Hi there</h1>
<div>my friend</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onmouseleave](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp) event to handle what happens when the mouse is not on the elements.

You can have a boolean value for each element that you set to true when the user hovers over them and false when the user leaves them. Then you can have an if statement in your onmouseleave event handler that checks whether the mouse is not on either of the elements.

```
//Get your h1 element
//Get your div element
var onH1 = false;
var onDiv = false;

function changeBoth() {
  //Change both borders
}

h1.onmouseover = function() {
  onH1 = true;
  //Change h1 border
}
div.onmouseover = function() {
  onDiv = true;
  //Change div border
}
h1.onmouseleave = function() {
  onH1 = false;
  if((!onH1) && (!onDiv)) {
    changeBoth();
  }
}
div.onmouseleave = function() {
  onDiv = false;
  if((!onH1) && (!onDiv)) {
    changeBoth();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I was thinking, I have hover set in CSS, should I change that to JavaScript to make this work better?

Comment: You should probably rename your existing hover CSS to a different name that is not set to hover. You can then use JS to handle the switches between classes using the classname property: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp If you need to support more than 1 class on your element at the same time, you can use classList https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp